# How to split elements within quotation marks

Tags: r

I want to seaparate this caracters:

```
v <- "a, b, c, d"
```

So the length of the vector is 4

```
v <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Comment: Use `strsplit`. `strsplit(v, ',')[[1]]`

Comment: or `strsplit(v, ', ')[[1]]` to remove the whitespace. Alternatively, you could use `scan(text=v, what='', sep=', ')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unlist()` converts the list to a character array

```
 v = unlist(as.vector(strsplit(x = v, split = ",")))
```